# Same functionality of MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem but "manually/programmatically" on iOS

Tags: ios, maps

I want to have the same functionality of MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem on a Map but I want to do it programmatically.

Normally using I do this on ViewController

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    ...
    MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem *buttonItem = [[MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem alloc] initWithMapView:self.map];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = buttonItem;
    ...
}
```

But I want to try it by code. I know how to get the UserLocation, but how can I get the compass functionality?

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old post but isn't compass functionality the "heading"? And so, you can set the tracking mode of the map by changing the userTrackingMode of the MKMapView.